# SQLAlchemy: how to model relationship where each referenced dataset (time series) is in a separate table

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, time-series, psycopg2

I am looking at modelling the following data sets using *either* SQLAlchemy or psycopg2, and would like to know if it's possibly to do it using SQLAlchemy.

I have a set of the following python objects:

```
import pandas as pd
class TimeSeriesWithMetadata:
    def __init__(self, metadata: dict, timeseries: pd.Series):
        self.metadata = metadata # {'metadata': ..., 'metadata2': ...}
        self.timeseries = timeseries # pandas Series Key:Value
        self.db_tstablename = None
        ....
```

I need the metadata of all objects to be stored in the same table, but each time series in their own table i.e.

```
Table "Metadata":
ID METADATA1 METADATA2 TSTABLENAME
 1 foo       bar       ab4652e34
 2 baz       acme      6359e248b 

Table "ab4652e34":
ID KEY                VALUE
 1 2018-08-07 00:00   0.697
 2 2019-08-07 00:00   0.314

Table "6359e248b":
ID KEY                VALUE
 1 2018-08-01 00:00   0.826
 2 2019-08-02 00:00   0.942
```

i.e. the foreign key in "Metadata" is another table's name and not a value from another table.

I am a total newbie with SQLAlchemy, and looking at tutorials and the full documentation, only could find help on how to model the relations with the static table names.

Is there a way to achieve the above in SQLAlchemy, or should I revert to the lower-level DB operations (psycopg2) and implement all the insertions/updates/deletes myself?

Comment: Why do you want to create a new table for each timeseries? That would bypass some of the most basic advantages of a relational database system. Furthmore i think it won't be possible with sqlalchemy and not a good idea to do with basic sql oprations either.

Comment: I agree with @FlorianH, just have a single table for all your timeseries records and relate them to a dataset with an identifying column that would hold your `"ab4652e34"` identifier per record.

Comment: Apart from the designer's view "we don't want to mix different time series together into the same table", one more reason is that in the future there will be a need for categorical-value time series, i.e. just having 1 table with key:string and value:double will be insufficient

Comment: Relational databases are capable of modeling all the requirements you mentioned without having an own table for every timeseries.